# sql to get distinct records

Tags: mysql, sql

need help with a query to get distinct records from the table.
this is for displaying in inbox area.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(from_id),to_id,message,sent_date,status,message_status from messages where to_id='$mid'
```

with this one i am get two records of from_id

```
SSM5130     testing         7 December
SSM4228     testing         9 December
SSM4228     testing         7 December
SSM12       Hai             7 December
SSM5130     aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa      6 December
```

but i need to get something like this.

```
SSM5130     testing         7 December
SSM4228     testing         9 December
SSM12       Hai             7 December
```

my database is something like this........

```
mes_id  to_id   from_id message                 date                read_status message_status
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       SSM11   SSM13   dfsdfsfsfsdfsdfsd       2013-12-06 10:49:44 1           0
2       SSM11   SSM5130 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  2013-12-06 10:52:01 1           0
3       SSM11   SSM5130 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  2013-12-06 10:52:14 1           0
4       SSM11   SSM4228 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  2013-11-01 09:30:30 1           0
41      SSM11   SSM12    Hai                    2013-12-07 12:50:13 1           0
43      SSM11   SSM5130 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  2013-11-07 09:30:30 1           0
44      SSM11   SSM100  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  2013-11-07 09:30:30 1           0
46      SSM11   SSM5130 testing                 2013-12-09 15:16:25 1           1
47          SSM5130   SSM11 testing                 2013-12-09 15:16:25     1           1
```

Comment: which database are you using, `sql server` or `mysql`?

Comment: Please show sample data from your `messages` table not the result of your query

Comment: In standard SQL, DISTINCT applies to all the values in the select-list, not to the first, or to the parenthesized list of values. You just chose to parenthesize the first value; SQL doesn't care. Drop the parentheses around `from_id` and see that you get the same result.  Your query is probably rather more complex than you specified.  Do you need the row with the maximum date value for a given `from_id`? It can be done, but it isn't trivial.  See questions with the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag for examples.

Answer (score 1):

You need to order every row by to_id and select first row for each to_id group.

```
SELECT
    t.mes_id,
    t.to_id,
    t.from_id,
    t.message,
    t.date,
    t.read_status,
    t.message_status
FROM
    (SELECT
        @row_num := IF(@prev_value=o.to_id, @row_num + 1, 1) AS RowNumber,
        @prev_value := o.to_id,
        o.*
    FROM
        my_table o,
        (SELECT @row_num := 1) X, (SELECT @prev_value := '') Y
    ORDER BY
        o.to_id) t
 WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: Analog in MsSql is ROW_NUMBER(). In MySql you need use this hack.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your existing from_id contain trailing spaces.

Use this query:

```
select distinct (ltrim(rtrim(from_id))), to_id,message,sent_date,status,message_status
  from messages
 where to_id='$mid'
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:** If understand correctly try it this way

```
SELECT m.* 
  FROM 
(
  SELECT to_id, from_id, MAX(date) date
    FROM messages  
   WHERE to_id='SSM11'   -- if you need it for a specific to_id 
   GROUP BY to_id, from_id
) q JOIN messages m
    ON q.to_id = m.to_id
   AND q.froM_id = m.from_id
   AND q.date = m.date
```

Output:

```
+--------+-------+---------+------------------------+---------------------+-------------+----------------+
| mes_id | to_id | from_id | message                | date                | read_status | message_status |
+--------+-------+---------+------------------------+---------------------+-------------+----------------+
|      1 | SSM11 | SSM13   | dfsdfsfsfsdfsdfsd      | 2013-12-06 10:49:44 |           1 |              0 |
|     41 | SSM11 | SSM12   | Hai                    | 2013-12-07 12:50:13 |           1 |              0 |
|     44 | SSM11 | SSM100  | aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa | 2013-11-07 09:30:30 |           1 |              0 |
|     46 | SSM11 | SSM5130 | testing                | 2013-12-09 15:16:25 |           1 |              1 |
|     51 | SSM11 | SSM4228 | testing                | 2013-12-09 15:03:51 |           0 |              1 |
+--------+-------+---------+------------------------+---------------------+-------------+----------------+
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/821b23/1)** demo

Comment: @user3024125 For that just a where clause in the derived table `q`. See updated answer

Comment: Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?